# Macros, Scripts, or an Ant-like function within Xamarin Studio to copy files

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-studio

Other than running a separate .bat file after each build, is there any way to automatically copy a compiled dll to a specified destination folder outside of the regular compile output folders?  I don't want to move the entire release folder, just a single compiled dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the easiest way is to create a .bat file which does the copy, and then create a custom command (in build options) which runs that bat file. Much better than running the bat file manually afterwards...